# Cable management in HP branded networking racks

Tags: networking, hp, rackmount, cable-management

I have HP 11842 racks (H6J69A) for networking equipment.

Does anyone use those in their datacenters? Some advice for cable management inside the rack would be highly useful. Photos from existing installations welcome!

Currently I'm investigating what are the best practices for cable management.
The idea is to mount networking equipment with ports to the front of the rack and to use patch panels with the same orientation in order to keep the airflow front-to-back.
My concern is that there's no vertical cable management on the front side of the rack. At least i don't see HP offering a kit beside D-rings.

Also, if the ports are located on the front, is there a need to move the vertical bars to the back from their standard/delivery position in order to accomodate the cables?

Comment: What will you be mounting in the rack? Specific equipment.

Comment: One rack should be strictly for ODF, optical patch pannels connected to various racks for TOR setup; there will also be a opto patch pannel to two racks with core network equipment - extreme networks BD8800 and x670 series.

Comment: I don't like putting core network gear in enclosures. A 2-post relay rack is much cleaner for this purpose, no?